# write to eventfd using Linux AIO

Tags: c, linux, performance, linux-kernel, aio

My application serve as high performance server to other applications running on system. During development I measured that about 30% of the core is consumed only to call eventfd_write() so tried to use libaio to write multiple evenfd using single syscall. An then I discovered that AIO is not supported for eventfd.

Is there any obvious obstacle to not implement AIO for eventfd or just no one needed this for now?

Do you know any existing work that try implement AIO for eventfd?

Comment: A read/write from/to an eventfd only deals with reading or writing an 8-byte integer in RAM. I suppose that doing the same thing via AIO adds a disproportionate overhead. Therefore there is no benefit in using AIO for that.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but when issuing 1M eventfd_writes per second to about 30 or more different eventfd it starts metter every syscall and this is why this question is asked to reduce syscall count by issuing couple of writes at once.

Comment: "1M eventfd_writes per second" ← there's your problem. Do you really have 1M different events? Or are they actually read that often?

Comment: Yes, this is required by client. In fact I'm able to serve some more requests than 1M/sec but about 1M of them have to be signaled.
I think I will experimnt on extending eventfd for AIO just to see if this introduce any measurable performance boost.

Comment: I do not think you're going to get the performance you need out of io_submit.  In the things I've done with it, its execution time has always scaled up with the number of entries in the iovec.  It's not as bad as O(N), but you certainly don't get to submit >1 requests for the cost of a one-request io_submit.  I think you'd be better served by coming up with a way to coalesce the signalling, perhaps coming up with an out-of-band protocol to handle several "events" with one eventfd write.

Answer (score 1):

Despite writing to eventfd is just a write to a memory, the write itself is a syscall. So you CPU has to switch a context, jump into the kernel, do a quick write and then switch back to your userspace application.

The context switch costs a lot, much more that just a single 64 bit write.

What options do we have?

1. Do not use an eventfd, use an atomic flag in a shared memory. You will eliminate syscalls and your performance will increase significantly.
2. Do not write to eventfd on each event:

   - Consider to group your events in batches and write just once per batch.
   - Consider to switch to a polling mode  once you have a non-empty queue of events and then switch back once the queue is empty again.
3. Move eventfd write to a separate thread, if it make sense in your context.

I am sure you know your application better, so you will come up with few more optimizations... If not - just ask on the StackOverflow ;)

Comment: Suggestion number one is not really viable if the eventfd is monitored with select/poll/epoll : there's no way that I know of to make an ordinary atomic flag I/O-multiplexable.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar I suggested to use atomic flags to avoid system calls. Because we need more performance. Sure, it means we do polling, not just wait for an event. Not quite understood the " I/O-multiplexable" part. Could you please elaborate?